# Unable to boot windows after installing drivers for graphics card

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, graphics-card

I have a laptop Samsung Chronos 700z (I don't remember exact model number, and I don't have laptop in front of me to check, I can update it later if required)

Recently, while I was browsing internet, laptop suddenly turned off. I tried turn it on, but during loading OS it shuts itself down. Initially I thought it is because it was overheated, so after it cooled down, I used compressed air to remove all dust.

But this didn't solve problem. It worked when I run windows in safe mode, so I thought it was some issues with system, so i reinstalled system.
After I reinstalled new system on the top of old one, and everything seems working fine, till I install graphics card drivers. I got exactly same issues as i had at the beginning.

Other thing, I tried to run linux from live cd, and it didn't work.

Anyone have suggestion what i should do, or at least idea what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were just graphics drivers, I've had this a number of times. Especially blue screen when booting or simply freezing. Reinstalling (fixing a botched install) can sometimes fix, or even better, roll back to an older driver version (fixing buggy drivers), making sure to choose stable and not beta drivers.

It looks like your laptop has integrated graphics. Perhaps when ever the OS tries to start the GPU it fails and the live CD has nouveau, doing the same. First thing I'd try is changing the primary graphics option in the BIOS if there is one, or disabling one of onboard or GPU graphics. This might get you to a point where you can try installing different driver versions or at least help narrow down the problem.

It may be the GPU is simply at fault and needs replacing. Hopefully still under warranty.

If you need to boot into linux without graphics, [edit the grub command line](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/howto-change-runlevel-on-grub2/) and throw a " 3" at the end.

Updating the BIOS might help.

I doubt this is the problem given your description, but running some kind of memcheck program (from a cd/usb at boot) might be worth a shot to see if the system ram is failing. I've had it once before and can cause some odd behaviour.

Comment: memorycheck didn't found any problems, and i don't have functionality to disable graphics card in bios. if gpu really required replacement, do you know where i can get it?

Comment: @user902383 If different drivers, a system reinstall and bios update don't solve the problem it certainly sounds like a hardware issue. If its new I'd start with the place you got it and if they don't help, contact samsung directly. Not sure about replacement GPUs for laptops sorry.

Comment: anyway thank you for help, ill try to reinstall system again, with everything clean, and seems like i need to contact samsung. Unfortunately warranty passed while ago

Comment: @user902383 hopefully samsung will be able to tell you how to make sure it's a hardware fault. you don't want to waste money on a replacement if it's just a bios setting or driver issue. had a quick look and doesn't seem like many others have the same issue. maybe [this](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2385576/switchable-graphic-card-boot-windows.html).